# Como usar SafariViewController em todas as URLs do App

Tags: swift, xcode, safari

Possuo um App que se apresenta inicialmente com uma `TableViewController` em que cada célula leva a uma `ViewController` simples.

Porém cada ViewController apresenta **muitas URLs que são reconhecidas automaticamente dentro de TextViews** e seria muito desgastante utilizar um processo de SafariVC para cada URL.

[image: ViewController]

Então, como eu faço para as URLs do `TextView` abrirem um `SafariViewController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo usar o [CSafariWebKit](https://github.com/dmandarino/CSafariWebKit)

No seu arquivo

```
import CSafariWebKit
```

Declare

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Essa função é disparada quando uma célula é selecionada. E então pegue sua url no na célula desse IndexPath e chame o SafariViewController conforme abaixo.

```
let vc = SafariViewController(url: url, barTintColor: nil, tintColor: nil)
vc.presentSafari(fromViewController: self, whenDidFinish: nil)
```

Use as cores do seu app para uma melhor experiência.